# ObjectMapper Unresolved identifier 'Mapper'

Tags: ios, json, objectmapper, swift2

My taskModel class file

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

// Mappeable source code
public protocol Mappable {
    init?(_ map: Map)
    mutating func mapping(map: Map)
}

// Conform to the Mappable protocol
class taskModel: Mappable {
    var taskid: Int = 0
    var parentId: Int = 0
    var taskname : String = ""
    var createdBy : String = ""
    var startDate : String = ""
    var taskStatus  : String = ""
    var Color : String = ""

    init(){

    }
    // MARK: Mappable
    required init?(_ map: Map) {
        // subClasses must call the constructor of the base class
        // super.init(map)
    }

    // Mappable
   func mapping(map: Map) {
        taskid    <- map["username"]
        parentId         <- map["age"]
        taskname      <- map["weight"]
        createdBy       <- map["arr"]
        startDate  <- map["dict"]
        taskStatus  <- map["best_friend"]
        Color     <- map["friends"]

    }
}
```

MyViewController

```
let taskJson = "{\"\"success\": true,\"\"messages\": \"successfully\",\"\"data\": [\"\"{\"\"\"\"taskId\": \"264\",\"\"\"\"parentId\": null,\"\"\"\"taskName\": \"order\",\"\"\"\"createdBy\": \"xyz\",\"\"\"\"assignedto\": \"xyz\",\"\"\"\"startDate\": \"23/11/2016\",\"\"\"\"taskStatus\": \"Open\",\"\"\"\"Color\": \"#6bea66\"\"\"}\"]}";

let repo = Mapper<taskModel>().map(taskJson)
```

[image]

I tried with importing ObjectMapper then its shows,
[image]

I would request you to please give me a Complete Example if I am doing mistake anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import ObjectMapper

class LiveNewsInterector: PresentorToInterectorProtocol{

    var presenter: InterectorToPresenterProtocol?;

    func fetchLiveNews() {
        Alamofire.request(Constants.URL).responseJSON { response in

            if(response.response?.statusCode == 200){
                if let json = response.result.value as! AnyObject? {
                    let arrayResponse = json["articles"] as! NSArray
                    let arrayObject = Mapper<LiveNewsModel>().mapArray(JSONArray: arrayResponse as! [[String : Any]]);
                    self.presenter?.liveNewsFetched(news: (arrayObject?[0])!);
                }
            }
            else {
                self.presenter?.liveNewsFetchedFailed();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[I get this from here](https://github.com/smalam119/live-news-viper/blob/master/Live%20News/modules/interector/LiveNewsInterector.swift)

Update Pods and clean build folder resolve my issue.
Hope this Help You!!